# how to measure time in linux?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I want to write data into a file when given time parameter :
for example I get x= 7 -> meaning for the next 7 seconds write some random data into a file
I got some difficulties doing that , 
I've tried using : clock() and struct timeval but it didn't work

things I've tried:

```
struct timeval start, end;
gettimeofday(&start, 0);
while(  gettimeofday(&end, 0) && end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec < sec )
  {
    write....
  }
```

but it stops the clock..

would love to get some help.
thanks

Comment: Consider switching to [clock_*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) functions... (`gettimeofday()` is marked obsolescent by POSIX).

Comment: @WilliamPursell I looked at the alarm but didn't understand how to use it , if i set it to alarm(0) how can I count how many seconds have passed?

Comment: You don't count.  You call `alarm` and then enter an "infinite" loop writing data.  When the timer expires, you exit the loop.  `alarm` is clumsy (1 second resolution), but there are many different types of timers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If [`getTimeOfDay`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) succeeds, it returns 0, and then your `while` condition fails. Try:

```
while(  (gettimeofday(&end, 0) == 0) && end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec < sec )
{
    write....
}
```

Comment: but then doesn't it stop the clock?

Comment: No, you check if the function succeeded, if it did, you check the values and if you are still the time period, you enter the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Consider order of operations... Try adding parens around the operands of `&&`</del>

man: [*gettimeofday()*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html)

```
RETURN VALUE
    The `gettimeofday()` function shall return 0 and 
    no value shall be reserved to indicate an error.
```

In you code because  gettimeofday() returns 0 on success while loops break.

Below you code rectified with `!` logical Not operator.

```
while(  (!gettimeofday(&end, 0)) && end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec < sec )
  {
    write....
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean ? There's no problem with the order of operations as far as I can tell.

Comment: the problem is that the first time I use the (&end,0) the clock is no longer counting ..am I wrong?

Comment: While adding parenthesis is clearer, this is not the problem here --> http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: why did you do that?? why would you edit a wrong answer and correct it? this doesn't make *any* sense.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath my mistake sorry Please check if it know correct. My Request..thanks in advance!

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: care to explain what the heck are you doing?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It was by mistake only. will remember next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `clock_gettime` instead of `gettimeofday` which is claimed to be obselete by `POSIX.1-2008`.

```
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec start, end;
    int sec = 10; // Number of seconds

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    while( !clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end)
           && end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec < sec )
    {
        // Write ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If you're using `gcc` or `g++` to compile your program, you need to link against the `librt` library by appending `-lrt`:

```
gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram -lrt
```

Comment: thanks! Im pretty new with linux so Im not sure I understood the difference between using clock_gettime ant getttimeofday. and what does the librt -lrt does? thank you